# How to go through a list of files

Tags: python, list, loops, csv

I'm trying to make a script that will run through a list of words one at a time and insert it in 3 areas on the script before starting over again. Then when it reaches the end of the list to stop.

```
wordlist = ['word1','word2','word3']
```

runs through `word1`

```
csvinput = 'mainfile.csv'

reader = csv.reader(open(r'{0}'.format(csvinput)), delimiter=',') 
filtered = filter(lambda p: 'word1' == p[6], reader) 
csv.writer(open(r"word1\word1.csv",'w', newline = ''),delimiter=',').writerows(filtered)
time.sleep(0.1)
```

then starts over again but on `word2` etc.. until it reaches the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
csvinput = 'mainfile.csv'
reader = csv.reader(open(r'{0}'.format(csvinput)), delimiter=',')

for word in wordlist:
    filtered = filter(lambda p: word == p[6], reader) 
    csv.writer(open("{}\{}.csv".format(word, word),'w', newline = ''),delimiter=',').writerows(filtered)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Some general documentation about looping through values: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html#iterators
https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

Comment: thank you! iterators was what I was looking for too. Only issue is it seems to be stopping to insert the data after `word1` but it does create the files. I think it might be a problem with the `filter`

Comment: Have you got an example of the mainfile.csv ? There may be a simpler way of achieving the result.

Comment: its working now! I had to move `csvinput` and `reader` into your loop

Comment: Glad it's working, but I feel like it's going to be very inefficient - basically you're reading the whole file three times. Might not be something you need to worry about here, but will certainly start to take a toll if you start to scale this up.